# How do I add correct information next to each typo in the "for" loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a typo detecting tool.

Here is my code:

```
from functools import partial

def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word

wrong = ['mann','connaction','tee','rigt','putt']
sentence=['this mann is my son','the connaction is unstable','my tee is getting cold','put your hands down','rigt now','right behind my back']

for i in wrong:
    print(f"Wrong: {i}")
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=i), sentence)
    for name in filtered_names:
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
Wrong: mann
this mann is my son
Wrong: connaction
the connaction is unstable
Wrong: tee
my tee is getting cold
Wrong: rigt
rigt now
Wrong: putt
```

Although it could help me detect typo in labels(mann,connaction,tee....),  but how could I add a correct word next to each labels?

Like:

```
Wrong: mann "should be man"
this mann is my son
Wrong: connaction "should be connection"
the connaction is unstable
Wrong: tee "should be tea"
my tee is getting cold
Wrong: rigt "should be right"
rigt now
Wrong: putt
```

Also, I want

> "Wrong:putt"

disappears if it doesn't really detect this kind of typo.

How could I make it? Please help

Comment: I would use tuples in wrong, with the correct word as the 2nd item in the tuple. Then it's quite easy to fix your code...

Comment: please tell me what 2nd item is? why it's quite easy to fix my code with tuple instead of list?

Answer (score 0):

With tuples including the wrong and the correct word, it's quite easy to fix your code. See this first version, where you just have to fix the format of what you want to display:

```
from functools import partial

def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word

wrong = [('mann','man'),('rigt','right')]
sentence=['this mann is my son','the connaction is unstable','my tee is getting cold','put your hands down','rigt now','right behind my back']

for i in wrong:
    print(f"Wrong: {i[0]}")
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=i[0]), sentence)
    for name in filtered_names:
        print(name)
        print(i[1])
```

I changed the content of wrong, and added the [0] after i where needed.